# Embedding python with f-strings

Tags: python, embedding

I am using python to create a random problem every time I compile the file

> input{|python3 0.py}

Its content is something like

`import random
a = random.randint(1,9)
b = random.choice(["a","b","c"])
c = random.randint(1,9)
d = random.choice(["a","b","c"])`

print(r"$\begin{bmatrix}%d &%s\%d %s\end{bmatrix}$" % (a, b, c, d) )

I have tried python-tex to do a similar thing but when importing a module, it did not go well.

My question is more python. I prefer using f-string to % formatting, but there are many occasions that I have to use curly braces in LaTeX, and I don't know how to differentiate formatting {} and the plain {} in f-strings. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, the Python experts are not here. Nevertheless I have some Python-defined functions that allow me to use the syntax e.g. `printz(r"x = %x%, y = %y%")` i.e. use `%` (or `!`, etc.) to delimit the things to evaluate

Comment: There are a few answers over on SO covering things like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-print-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format/40877821#40877821 And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-print-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format/40877821#comment83382080_5466451 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example using the [`pyluatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pyluatex) package (run with LuaLaTeX and `--shell-escape`).

To get curly braces in an `f`-string, you have to use two of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pyluatex}

\begin{python}
import random
a = random.randint(1, 9)
b = random.choice(["a", "b", "c"])
c = random.randint(1, 9)
d = random.choice(["a", "b", "c"])

def print_matrix():
    return rf'\begin{{bmatrix}} {a} & {b} \\ {c} & {d} \end{{bmatrix}}'
\end{python}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \py{a} & \py{b} \\
        \py{c} & \py{d}
    \end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
    \py{print_matrix()}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly not what OP asks for i.e. avoid the cumbersome syntax of doubling `{{`. (correction, on another read OP said "don't know how to" so... this is a valid solution I guess.